# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__platform_browser_private__' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have upgraded my project to angular 2.2.3 (`nodejs: 6.9.1, typescript 2.0.3`) I am also using @types and got rid off typings.json.

```
"@types/node": "^6.0.51",
"@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38"
```

my main.ts looks as follows:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__platform_browser_private__' of undefined router.umd.js:3767
```

I cannot understand what am I doing wrong. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Angular 2.2.3 does not exist yet... https://github.com/angular/angular/milestones

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core